# Spring WebFlux, unit testing Mono and Flux

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Interested in reactive programming, I played a bit with the [Building a Reactive RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/) guide. And wanted to move forwrad and add some unit tests.

I tried to test my handler (`RouterFunction`) with plain Junit/Mockito test. But, because it is reactive, the handler returns a `Mono<ServerResponse>`. So I had to `block()` it to test the `ServerResponse` status but was not able to extract his body to test it. While searching the web for a solution, it seems that all the samples are using the `WebTestClient`.

**My question is:**

Given that all samples are using `WebTestClient` to test a reactive REST service and that it is not easier to (unit) test the body of a `ServerResponse`. Is it a good practice to unit test a `RouterFunction` or is it better to always do broader tests with the `WebTestClient` ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm afraid it may end up as primarily opinion-based, but as I'm not especially familiar with WebFlux there may be a helpful best practice here.

Comment: Thanks. Of course it will be opinion-based, but the web tends to say that there is no other clean way than testing it with the `WebTestClient`. So either I am searching in the wrong way or there is no other way.

Comment: Have you read [the testing section](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing) of Project Reactor Reference?

Comment: Yes. My problem was (see answer) more about testing the body of a `ServerResponse`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the best practice is to use the `WebTestClient`. However this one can be used without a running server;

> The `spring-test` module includes a `WebTestClient` that can be used to test WebFlux server endpoints **with or without a running server**.
>
> -- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-tests

Comment: Note that it doesn't yet work with Kotlin very well ([issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16057))

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what exactly you want to test, for regular method you should use **StepVerifier** in favor of consume the output of you test. However **router functions** are unique, because, usually return a **serverResponse** that contains your data on body, so in that case its better use **webClient** or **webTestClient**.