# how can I do an Unit Test below code using WebFlux and Java 8?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to create a Unit Test this code using WebFlux but I don't know how to do that, I need to cover 100% call method below in the unit  test.

```
@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;

public String call(final String xml) {
    return this.webClient.post().uri("URL")
                         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                         .body(Mono.just(xml),String.class)
                         .retrieve()                             
                         .bodyToMono(String.class)
                         .block();
}
```

thank you so how much who can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring WebFlux, unit testing Mono and Flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830411/spring-webflux-unit-testing-mono-and-flux)

Comment: it is not duplicate question @EmreSavcı

Comment: You can use WebTestClient, check here https://www.callicoder.com/spring-5-reactive-webclient-webtestclient-examples/ .. and also StepVerifier is possible, read here: http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#testing

Comment: Just a note on the code: The "block()" in the end smells a bit, since you don't really win anything by using a reactive webclient, if you're leaving the reactive world right at the end of the method.

Comment: @Frischling I need that method return a string value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really unit test this, you'd have to do an integration test. Spin up your own Webserver, serving the content that helps in your test. At least that's my only idea for this.

Take a look at this here:

https://mock-server.com/mock_server/running_mock_server.html

Answer (score 1):

Mocking the `WebClient` using a library like [`mockito`](https://site.mockito.org/) is your best bet if you want to unit test this, but the function looks more deserving of an integration test as you'd really only be testing the mock's functionality at that point.